# How to use websocket with laravel and react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, mongodb, socket.io

I am trying to get in real time the update in my data base

I have made the connection with my mongodb database in laravel and it is working (i can put, delete, get my offers)

I am using :

- "laravel/framework": "^9.0",
- "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.9",
- "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.14",

Now, i would like in real time see the change in my front
For exemple, if user1 create an offer, user2 need to see the offer from user1 without reloading the application.

I was thinking using :

- watch() from mongodb to listen the change.
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets to see in real time the data in laravel
- then socket.io-client in react

First I have made the laravel configuration

I have made a provider

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Http\Middleware\WatchMongoDB;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Facades\WebSocketsRouter;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        WebSocketsRouter::channel('my-channel', function ($data, $client) {
            // Diffuser les données aux clients connectés
            $client->broadcast()->toOthers()->emit('my-event', $data);
        })->middleware([
            new WatchMongoDB(), // middleware to detect the mongdb change
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
}
```

config the webscokets file

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('MONGO_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'), //MONGO_DB_DATABASE_NAME
        'key' => env('MONGO_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('MONGO_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('DB_URI'),
        'capacity' => env('MONGO_APP_CAPACITY'),
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```

made a middleware

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Models\InternOrders;

class WatchMongoDB
{
    //Le middleware WatchMongoDB utilise maintenant la méthode watch() de la classe InternOrders en passant la fonction $callback pour traiter les changements de la collection MongoDB.
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Fonction callback pour traiter les changements de la collection
        $callback = function ($change) {
            // Récupérer le type d'opération (insert, update, delete)
            $operationType = $change['operationType'];

            // Récupérer le document modifié
            $document = $change['fullDocument'];

            // Traiter le changement en fonction de son type
            switch ($operationType) {
                case 'insert':
                    // Le document a été inséré dans la collection
                    // Faire quelque chose avec le document inséré
                    break;

                case 'update':
                    // Le document a été mis à jour dans la collection
                    // Récupérer les champs modifiés
                    $updatedFields = $change['updateDescription']['updatedFields'];

                    // Faire quelque chose avec les champs modifiés
                    break;

                case 'delete':
                    // Le document a été supprimé de la collection
                    // Faire quelque chose avec le document supprimé
                    break;
            }
        };

        InternOrders::watch($callback);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My model i want to listen :

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class InternOrders extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';

    protected $fillable = [
        'History', 'Urls', 'Amount', 'BusinessUnit', 'Comment', 'DeliveryAdress', 'Entity', 'Express', 'ExpressObject', 'Object', 'Paiement', 'Referent', 'Status', 'Type', 'UserMail', 'UserName',
    ];

    // Méthode pour regarder une collection MongoDB
    public static function watch($callback)
    {
        $model = new static;

        $collection = $model->getConnection()->getCollection('intern_orders');

        $changeStream = $collection->watch([], ['fullDocument' => 'updateLookup']);

        foreach ($changeStream as $change) {
            $callback($change);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know if I am doing the right way to listen and update in real time my data ?

Actually, when I run php artisan websockets:serve i got Error

```
'Call to undefined method BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Server\Router::channel()
  1   C:\code\Orders\back\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php:17
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()   

  2   C:\code\Orders\back\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php:36
      App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::boot()
'.
```

I have already tried cache:clear and config:cache but with no success
I have also tried to replace in my providers "channel" by "on" and "route" with no success

Comment: why can't you use Laravel Event Broadcasting it will have proper doccumentation with examples.

Comment: I want to use watch from mongodb instead of pusher